# Есть ли способ выполнить sql запрос на который не хватает памяти?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Делаю запрос в ClickHouse. В самом запросе есть группировка и из-за этого ему требуется больше оперативной памяти, чем выделено по умолчанию. Возможно ли каким-то образом избежать этого ограничения, например выполняя запрос итерационно или еще как-то? Объем группируемых данных примерно 750 миллионов строк. Запрос такого вида: `select text, groupUniqArray(pid) min(date), max(date) from table group by text having uniq(pid)>1`.

Comment: Если на уровне чистого SQL ещё можно было бы что-то сказать, то вот что там под капотом у ClickHouse - вообще фиг знает. Можете, конечно, искусственно поделить запрос на чанки по полю группировки (`where text like 'a%'`, `where text like 'b%'` и т.д.) - но будет ли с того толк... попробуйте.

Comment: @Akina Уже пробовал нечто подобное и появляется 2 проблемы: главное - groupUniqArray(pid) не сделает правильную группировку, если text одного и того же pid будет начинаться с a и b. Второе - перекос в группируемых значениях - тех же строк, начинающихся с a будет миллион, а с b - 100 миллионов. И я правильно понимаю, что вы имели ввиду разбить запрос на несколько?

Comment: *главное - groupUniqArray(pid) не сделает правильную группировку, если text одного и того же pid будет начинаться с a и b.* Не понял... функция лезет в "не свою" группу? т.е. выполняет независимый запрос в ту же таблицу? *я правильно понимаю, что вы имели ввиду разбить запрос на несколько?* Да. *строк, начинающихся с a будет миллион, а с b - 100 миллионов.* Значит, вторую надо будет мельче шинковать.

Comment: @Akina, насчет главной проблемы - наверное я не прав, кажется не совсем правильно себе это представлял. А насчет шинковки просто думал, возможно есть более изящное решение, чем выполнять вместо одного запроса условные 26.

Comment: Может, и есть... с другой стороны лучше геморрой с 26 запросами, чем невыполненный по причине нехватки ресурсов запрос. А границы - их можно определить программно, причём заранее, ибо на таком объёме статистика если и ползёт, то достаточно небыстро.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо. Пока тогда буду использовать такой вариант. Быть может кто-то еще что-то сможет посоветовать.